# Qt TextLineEdit: Retrieve string instead of QString

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using Qt and want to get string from text field. I found below solution but it returns a QString. I just want to avoid writing extra code to extract string further. Can anyone suggest a simple solution to retrieve text from text field.

```py
text = self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *will* have to add some code to get a string from a `QLineEdit` object. Simplest solution: use the `str()` method.

`text = str( self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text() )`

Answer (score 1):

for example http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/qstring-normal-python-string-127725.html says:

```
text = str(self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text())
```

But i agree, it's a pitty we cant use strings easily in Qt.
other hints with Qt and strings: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html